# What is the right way to get updates from REST service by timer in Android?

Tags: android, rest

I wonder what is the right way to get updates from REST service by timer in Android?

May be I should use [timer task](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) for this?

**UPDATE: I need to receive updates even if user has switched to another application or receive a call. UI also should be updated. So when user switch back to the application he should see updated view.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that might help:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){ public void run()
        {onTimerTick();}}, 0, 1000L);

private onTimerTick_()
{
 // do REST call

}
```

You will want to make sure this is in a seperate thread.

Answer (score 1):

'The right' way depends on what you are trying to do. Update your GUI? Update a datastore in the background while the app is not visible? [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) lets you fire off a service to get data even if your app is not currently running, unlike TimerTask, so it's better for the second case.

Comment: I need to update singleton class instance and also reflect this changes to GUI. Application should grab updates even when user switched to another app or perhaps received a phonecall.

Comment: Your singleton class may die along with your process, if Android kills it while you are using other (memory intensive) apps. Do you need to get updates at a particular time? Why not simply get the updates when the user returns to the app? If you are trying to cache the data, so it's already available when they start/return to the app, you need to persist it somewhere (file, database, etc.). In that case, a service started by AlarmManager is a good choice.

Comment: Updates should be also reflected with StatusBarNotifications.

Comment: You are still not saying what exactly you want to achieve. You can have the service just check for updates, push a notification if there are any, and the app will get get the actual data when started from the notifications. Those are just ideas, you need to consider your actual use case/requirements to select what to use.